# How to join multiple distinct rows in one column

Tags: mysql, join, mariadb

I have 3 tables

Restaurants table:

| restaurant_id | restaurant_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Burger King |
| 2 | Coffee shop |

Foods table:

| food_id | food_title | category_id | restaurant_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Burger with cheese | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | Beef Burger | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | Beef Burger with cheese | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | Iced Coffee | 3 | 2 |
| 5 | Dark Coffee | 3 | 2 |
| 5 | Green Tea | 4 | 2 |

Categories table:

| category_id | category_title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Normal Burger |
| 2 | Beef Burger |
| 3 | Coffee |
| 4 | Tea |

The output I'm looking for:

| restaurant_id | restaurant_name | categories_list |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Burger King | [{category_id: 1, category_title: 'Normal Burger'}, {category_id: 2, category_title: 'Beef Burger'}] |
| 2 | Coffee shop | [{category_id: 3, category_title: 'Coffee'}, {category_id: 4, category_title: 'Tea'}] |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
    select restaurant_id,restaurant_name,concat('[',group_concat(my_col),']') as tot_result
from ( select r.restaurant_id,r.restaurant_name,concat('{category_id: ', c.category_id," category_title: '",c.category_title ,"'}") as my_col
       from Restaurants r
       inner join Foods f on r.restaurant_id=f.restaurant_id
       inner join Categories c on c.category_id=f.category_id
       group by r.restaurant_id,r.restaurant_name,my_col
     ) as t1
group by restaurant_id,restaurant_name;
```

Result:

```
restaurant_id   restaurant_name   tot_result
    1            Burger King    [{category_id: 1 category_title: 'Normal Burger'},{category_id: 2 category_title: 'Beef Burger'}]
    2            Coffee shop    [{category_id: 3 category_title: 'Coffee'},{category_id: 4 category_title: 'Tea'}]
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=be9e3b4de51898beb8534cae2bfe8683)

Comment: Thanks this worked great, Can I ask why you used `inner join` instead of `left join`?

Comment: @Nameer  I was based on your data examples and expected result. You can change it based on your real data. I hope that the query gives an good idea on how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Join `Restaurants` to `Foods` and `Categories` with `LEFT` joins and group by restaurant.
Then use [`JSON_ARRAYAGG()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg) aggregate function to get the lists:

```
SELECT r.restaurant_id, r.restaurant_name,
       JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('category_id', c.category_id, 'category_title', c.category_title)) categories_list
FROM Restaurants r
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT category_id, restaurant_id FROM Foods) f ON f.restaurant_id = r.restaurant_id
LEFT JOIN Categories c ON c.category_id = f.category_id
GROUP BY r.restaurant_id, r.restaurant_name;
```

I use `SELECT DISTINCT ...` in the table `Foods` because I see in your expected results that you want distinct categories in each list.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8f02ab298eb7f875c97dafbc2b624c80).

Comment: Using `SELECT DISTINCT ...` might improve performance, thanks